# Twitter post in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

I am working on an app where a user can login to their twitter account and post their status.
Everything is going well but when I click on the tweet button to post, the status doesn't update.

What is wrong with my code?

```
private void btnPostTweet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtBoxNewTweet.Text.Trim().Length == 0) { return; }

    var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
    {
        Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
        ConsumerKey = TwitterSettings.consumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = TwitterSettings.consumerKeySecret,
        Token = this.accessToken,
        TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
        Version = "1.0"
    };

    var restClient = new RestClient
    {
        Authority = TwitterSettings.StatusUpdateUrl,
        HasElevatedPermissions = true,
        Credentials = credentials,
        Method = WebMethod.Post
    };

    restClient.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Create a Rest Request and fire it
    var restRequest = new RestRequest
    {
        Path = "1/statuses/update.xml?status=" + txtBoxNewTweet.Text 
    };

    var ByteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtBoxNewTweet.Text);
    restRequest.AddPostContent(ByteData);
    restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of the last lines of your code

```
    restRequest = new RestRequest
    {
        Path = "1/statuses/update.xml"
    };
    restRequest.AddParameter("status", tbxNewTweet.Text);

    //var ByteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txtBoxNewTweet.Text);
    //restRequest.AddPostContent(ByteData);
    restClient.BeginRequest(restRequest, new RestCallback(PostTweetRequestCallback));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question, but if you use API twitter api 1.0, move to api 1.1 right now. They are going to retire api 1.0 next month: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/planning-for-api-v1-retirement.
Note, they are closing all but JSON, so your code might stop working at all at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Did you fine find the answer? If not please try with this:

```
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
    {
        Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
        ConsumerKey = TwitterSettings.consumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = TwitterSettings.consumerKeySecret,
        Token = this.accessToken,
        TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,
        Version = "1.0"
    };
```

Here remove  `Version = "1.0"`

So It will be look like this:

```
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
        {
            Type = OAuthType.ProtectedResource,
            SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
            ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
            ConsumerKey = TwitterSettings.consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = TwitterSettings.consumerKeySecret,
            Token = this.accessToken,
            TokenSecret = this.accessTokenSecret,            
        };
```

Then change the path:

```
var restRequest = new RestRequest
    {
        Path = "1.1/statuses/update.xml?status=" + txtBoxNewTweet.Text 
    };
```

And finally you have to check one thing. Your Application Settings in https://apps.twitter.com/

Change the Access level to `Read, write, and direct messages (modify app permissions)`

If you can not change the permissions mean try from your mobile. Go to this url from your mobile and log in with your user name and password. Now you can change the settings from mobile. Now you can Post your twit..!!